# How to remove saved email addresses from dropdown To: menu?

Tags: contacts, email

Native Android mail app using Exchange. Some email addresses are incomplete or incorrect in the dropdown list when adding recipients. I want to delete these. Anyone know how?

Comment: Are these emails tied to any of your contacts? If they are incorrect in the contact's details, they'll be incorrectly shown in the dropdown too.